# Remove Noise from m4b (audiobook) file

Tags: macos, audacity, audio-processing, m4b

I have an audiobook in m4b-format (with metadata such as chaptermarks etc) that unluckily contains a high pitched background noise.

What is the best tool/workflow for OS X to remove this unwanted noise while preserving the metadata?

I've already messed around with Audacity but it seems that the metadata gets lost in the process.